# True/False test: $P(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}.$ Then, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{P(x)}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

True/False test: $P(x)=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+...+\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$ where $n$ is a large positive integer. Then, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{e^x}{P(x)}=1$

[The paper](http://univ.tifr.res.in/gs2014/Files/GS2013_QP_MTH.pdf) says it's false but I can see since $P(x)\to e^x\ne0$ as $n\to\infty$ the sequence $P(x)$ is eventually nonzero and hence $\dfrac{1}{P(x)}\to\dfrac{1}{e^x}$ whence $\dfrac{e^x}{P(x)}\to1~(e^x$ being a constant)

So where did I go wrong?

Comment: What paper says it's false?

Comment: http://univ.tifr.res.in/gs2014/Files/GS2013_QP_MTH.pdf  Q.18

Comment: The paper says $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}$ not $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}$.

Comment: oHHHHHH NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer:

Toylor's expansion: $$e^x=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{n!}+\frac{e^c\: x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!},\: c\in(0;1)$$

Hence: $$\frac{e^x}{P(x)}=1+\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!P(x)}e^c\to 1$$

Comment: I think it tends to $\infty$. By repeated l hospital rule $e^x$ stays put while the $P(x)$'s degree keeps getting reduced by one.

Answer (score 4):

The exercise in the test is

> $P(x)=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+...+\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$ where $n$ is a large positive integer. Then, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{e^x}{P(x)}=1$

This is indeed false, because the limit is $\infty$. Indeed it's easy to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{x^n}=\infty
$$
for every natural $n$. Deriving from this the result for $P(x)$ is also easy.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't pay enough attention ! The limit has *x* tending towards infinity, **not** *n* !